# getMessage function of Zend_mail_storage_Pop3 returns trimmed header

Tags: php, iconv, zend-mail

I am using getMessage function of Zend_mail_storage_Pop3 class to fetch the mime message. My php version is 5.3.3. In some cases getMessage is not returning all the mime headers.

On further investigation I found getMessage function is internally calling [`iconv_mime_decode_headers`](http://php.net/iconv_mime_decode_headers) function and that seems to be trimming the headers in some conditions.

For example: 
If the subject header is: `Subject: Reply "Is? white side-LED =?=" in Help`
which contains the character `=?=`, then the rest of the headers after subject like content-type, date etc are not returned.

Is there a known bug in `iconv_mime_decode_headers`?
What could be a possible solution to this issue?

Comment: Is the code using `ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR`?

Comment: Yes ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR is used

Comment: Darn, that was the most likely suspect for this behavior... Is the encoded sequence *just* `=?=`, or is there more?

Comment: The Subject in not encoded, it contains this character without encoding

Comment: This points me to another question, when is the subject in the mime message encoded? In the above example if I increase the length of the subject then it gets encoded to ISO-8859-1. Why on changing the length of subject it gets encoded? What are the conditions in which the mime message gets encoded and does the client decide on when to encode the subject header of mime message?

Comment: It actually might depend on the client being used and what the local language is.  I've seen cases where clients will encode *anything* that isn't 7-bit ASCII clean into a giant UTF-8-encoded *mess*.